# Присвоение события объекту через DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Как присвоить событие объекту через DOM? Допустим, создал я

```
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
```

Как мне тегу `tr` присвоить событие `onclick`?

Answer (score 2):

```
tr.onclick = function(){
  //do something  
}
```

Comment: А другой вариант есть то это не подходит что та на подобие добавление <b>атрибутов </b>

Comment: не очень вас понял, не могли бы вы перефразировать?

Comment: Он наверное хотел спросить как сделать так?  
<tr onClick="test();return false;">  
Так сделать не получится, потому что DOM дерево этого элемента создаётся динамически в ходе работы скрипта. Либо если есть огромное желание, можете в самом документе заблаговременно создать <tr> со всеми атрибутами, и присвоить ему display: none

Answer (score 2):

без setTimeout или window.onload скрипт может не сработать в разных браузерах разных версий.

```
window.onload = fucntion(){
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.onclick = function(){
  //do something  
  }
}
```

Comment: setTimeout очень плохой подход для этого, лучше только window.onload

Comment: Прекрасно понимаю!

Answer (score 2):

еще как вариант -

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("I was clicked");
}

var tr = document.createElement("tr");
tr.onclick = myFunction;
```

PS: это в JQuery любое событие обычно описывается как **element.event(function)** но в языка семейства ECMAScript к которому относиться JS - функция это обьект. Это позволяет делать множество всяких вкустностей, как например вот здесь, или даже динамическое построение тела функции. Можно так-же, например, написать так чтобы события динамически переписывались, например:

```
element.onclick = myFunction;
    function myFunction() {
        // тут чтото делаем
        this.onclick = myAnotherFunction;
    }
    function myAnotherFunction() {
        alert("Теперь при клике будет вызываться эта функция");
    }
```

**Ответ на коммент:**
Практический смысл в том что вы можете "строить" код в процессе исполнения. Самый примитивный пример это любой переключатель. Но как вы понимаете, тот-же переключатель может быть намного сложнее чем тупо true false.
PS:это возможности языка, вам необязательно их использовать, но, думаю знать об этом никому не помешает..

Comment: А каков практический смысл такой реализации? (имеется ввиду второй кусок кода)

Answer (score 0):

Добавлять обработчик лучше используя `DOM2`, а не `DOM0`.

```
let tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.addEventListener('click',function()
{
    //Some code;
});
```

Comment: в чем смысл удаления предыдущего ответа?

Comment: @Grundy, Сначала я осознав своё заблуждение, решил его изменить, делая акцент на использование `DOM2`, но потом понял, что ставлю вас в глупое положение, с общим вопросом "В чём разница?", так как вопрос был изменён. Решил, что лучше удалить ответ полностью и ответить снова.
P.S. Надеюсь сейчас вы на зададите аналогичный вопрос. :-)

Comment: Не надейся :-) почему _Добавлять обработчик лучше используя DOM2, а не DOM0_? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE 1 `DOM2` - более современный метод, для меня уже одного этого достаточно. 2 `DOM0` имеет смысл использовать, только когда мы задаём обработчик через HTML-атрибут, например onclick 3 В случае объявления нового обработчика DOM0, он затрёт старый, в том числе и тот, который был определён через HTML-атрибут. 4 Его нельзя явно удалить.

Comment: как это нельзя удалить?

Comment: @Grundy, Не хватило символов в комментарии, что бы описать подробнее. :-)
Через `removeAtrribute('onclick')` удалить, конечно же, можно, но явного метода удаления `DOM0`-обработчиков в `JS` нет.

Comment: почему же? обычно присвоение _undefined_ вполне себе убирает обработчик

Comment: @Grundy, Согласен! Удалить можно и перезаписью пустым значением или неопределённым, но это не удаление, а перезапись. В моём понимании слова `явный`, должен быть явный метод удаления, который в `DOM2` есть - `removeEventListener`, а в `DOM0` нет. Я не имел ввиду, что нельзя удалить в принципе, я имел ввиду, что нет методов для явного удаления.